# Android device offline in Device Chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb, ddms

I have been searching for a few days now, here are the specs

- OS : Mac osx 10.11 (El Captain)
- Android SDK : recently downloaded
- Problem : My device is found but offline in device chooser

Here are a few steps I took to shoot the problem down

1. I connect the device with my Mac
2. I check in ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices
3. it shows my devices as
   **0123456789ABCDEF  device**
4. I launch my eclipse
5. start running my android application
6. My device chooser shows that device as offline
7. I again go to terminal and ./adb devices
8. Bang! it is offline **0123456789ABCDEF  offline**
9. when I shut down eclipse and restart adb server, `-kill-server and start-server` the device shows up in my Terminal correctly but when I launch my eclipse, it is offline again both in eclipse and terminal,
   sounds like it does not like my eclipse or something,

Please help, I am fairly new to mac and android. I tried all the recipe -kill-server, start-server, reboot device, no luck,
The device I tried used, to work on windows machine however,

Comment: 1. unplug/plug usb, add kill-server start-server, switch usb ports already tried with no luck. the thing is I can see the device without eclipse and even push apk files to device, but I want to debug  with eclipse DDMS and it goes offline with DDMS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@darkcloudbird see when i have same problem i do below step and i'm sure to resole it

1) First yes it silly but check your data-cable work properly or not ;-)
2) Attach your device normally
3) While connect your device check the alert msg in your device 
4) If device is LENOVO then please install it's USB support driver in your system

using this all trick though same issue kindly post your snapshot will help you.

Comment: Thanks i tried already those steps, the problem is that i can see my device in adb devices as long as i do not open eclipse ddms, when i open eclipse it is both offline in eclipse ddms and terminal adb devices,